# How to use the table and column name in a NEW record in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

How can I use the distinct name of a column together with the tablename for a new record? I tried something like that `NEW.table_name.column_name` e.g.:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION some_fun() 
    RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$func$

BEGIN

NEW.table1.column2 := sum(table3.cost) FROM table3 WHERE NEW.id = table3.d_id GROUP BY d_id;

NEW.table1.column3 := [...]


RETURN NEW;                       
END;
$func$ language plpgsql;
```

But I get:

```
ERROR:  "NEW.table1.column2" is not a known variable
```

Comment: `NEW` is an alias for the record that the trigger operates on.  try `NEW.column2`.  See [PostgreSQL Docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-trigger.html) for more info

Comment: Thanks @BillJetzer , is it somehow possible to set an alias which differs from the trigger reason? e.g. When insert on table1 ... execute something on table2

Comment: If you want to execute something on a table other than the table triggering the function, then just write any SQL statement that you like, while using the `OLD` or `NEW` aliases if needed.